# Is there a way to make text on canvas not blurry with only CSS properties?

Tags: canvas, text

I'm trying to draw text onto the canvas, however, the text looks very blurry. I've managed to fix the issue with the background images by setting smoothing to false and also using css to make the `image-rendering` for all canvases pixelated, but the same trick doesn't seem to work for text.

I've also read posts where some of the solutions mention using a set canvas size instead of sizing it in CSS; however, I've also tried that with a set pixel amount specified directly in the `canvas` tag and the text still looked blurry. And another solution mentioned high DPI and using retina display.

This is where I'm making the function call to draw the text (the score in the game):

```
// Drawing the game
  draw() {  
    this.gameCtx.clearRect(0, 0, this.gameCanvas.width, this.gameCanvas.height);

    // Drawing background
    this.background.draw();
    this.foreground.draw();

    // Drawing the score
    this.score.draw(this.gameCtx);

    // Adding enemies to game
    this.addEnemies();
  }

  // temp start function for game
  start() {        
    this.gameCanvas.focus();

    if (!this.gameOver) {
      this.draw();
      this.updateObjects(this.gameCtx);
      this.checkCollisions();
      this.checkPlayerCollisions();
      requestAnimationFrame(this.start.bind(this));
    }
  }
```

And this is the function that draws the actual text onto the canvas:

```
  // Drawing the Score
  draw(ctx) {
    const text = `Score: ${this.score}`;
    ctx.font = '10px Arial';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillText(text, 20, 20);
    this.addScore();
  }
```

Also, I'm not sure if this will affect how I need to display the text, but my goal is to make the canvas as large as the user's window; so that the game is a full screen game.

Currently this is what the score text looks like:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

The approach of using css to make the image-rendering pixelated is not ideal, If you can post a small code snippet of what you have so far we can try to do the same without css.

...and yes the `10px Arial` looks a bit blurry, perhaps a larger font might help.

```js
canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
ctx.fill();

ctx.fillStyle = 'white';

ctx.font = '10px Arial';
ctx.fillText("Score: 10px Arial", 20, 10);
ctx.font = '15px Arial';
ctx.fillText("Score: 15px Arial", 20, 28);
ctx.font = '20px Arial';
ctx.fillText("Score: 20px Arial", 20, 50);
```

```css
#canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" height=80>
```

---

Here is an example of how to pixelate an image

```js
var pixelated = null
var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/UFBxY.png";
image.onload = imageLoaded;

var size = 120;
var delta = 0.5;

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

function drawImage(img, x, y, size, filter) {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.filter = filter
  ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, size, size);
  ctx.closePath()
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  if (size > canvas.height || size < 120) {
    delta *= -1
  }
  size += delta;

  drawImage(image, 0, 0, size, 'blur(1px)');
  drawImage(image, 140, 0, size, 'none');
  drawImage(pixelated, 280, 0, size, 'none');
  ctx.font = '10px Arial';
  ctx.fillText("Score: 10px Arial", 110, 10);
}

function imageLoaded() {
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = image.width;
  c.height = image.height;
  c.style.cssText =
    'image-rendering: optimizeSpeed;' + // FireFox < 6.0
    'image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;' + // FireFox
    'image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;' + // Opera
    'image-rendering: -webkit-crisp-edges;' + // Chrome
    'image-rendering: crisp-edges;' + // Chrome
    'image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;' + // Safari
    'image-rendering: pixelated; ' + // Future browsers
    '-ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;';
  var ct = c.getContext('2d');
  ct.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ct.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ct.msImageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  ct.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  var w = c.width / 5;
  var h = c.height / 5;
  ct.globalCompositeOperation = 'copy';
  ct.drawImage(image, 0, 0, w, h);
  ct.drawImage(c, 0, 0, w, h, 0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  pixelated = c
  
  setInterval(draw, 20);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=500>
```

---

Now for obvious performance reasons you should avoid doing the pixelation client side, ideally all your images and sprites are pre-pixelated, that way you also avoid any browser compatibility issue:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering#Browser_compatibility

Comment: I'll give it a try! However, is there a way to make it even more clear? Similar to how text renders normally on a page in HTML tags? (i.e. a pargaraph/header tag, etc.) And just wondering, but does it matter that I'm setting the canvas to take up the entire screen of a user's window?

Comment: Yes you can make as clear as any text, just don't use CSS to do it

Comment: @Karen have you seen my updates to the question, I added a sample code to pixelate images on the canvas without external CSS applied to our final canvas, also added my thoughts on these approaches